# How to Make Layout composable have a transparent background in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, material-design

Hello guys I am using a Layout composable to implement Animated drawer but whenever I set the background of the  Layout to Transparent it become Black instead but if i provide other colors, they are applied. How do i work around this.

> Using the first code below gives it a white background as expected

```
@Composable
fun MyDrawer(
  drawer: @Composable () -> Unit,
  content: @Composable () -> Unit
){
  Layout(
        /*White (or any other colour provided) background as expected*/
        modifier = modifier.background(Colors.White),
        content = {
            drawer()
            content()
        }
    )
}
```

> But if i use the code below, the background becomes black rather than transparent and affects my bottom sheet.

```
@Composable
fun MyDrawer(
  drawer: @Composable () -> Unit,
  content: @Composable () -> Unit
){
  Layout(
        /*Black background instead of transparent*/
        modifier = modifier.background(Colors.Transparent),
        content = {
            drawer()
            content()
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: You should take a look from where the black comes, obviously it comes from a previous composable or even from a surface which have predifined background colors

Comment: I thought so initially and I had to define MaterialTheme.colors and setting the background to Transparent. Now It is showing white instead of the black